# sort and then merge only data that match certain criteria between two xml files, using xslt 3

Tags: xslt-3.0

given the following xml files:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <TABLE NAME="File_A">
        <DATA RECORDS="2">
            <RECORD ID="1">
                <PID>2</PID>
                <ENTRYDATE>4/12/2002</ENTRYDATE>
                <VERSIONID>28/12/2016</VERSIONID>
                <REGDATE>8/9/1986</REGDATE>
                <EXPIREDDATE>12/2/2010</EXPIREDDATE>
                <TOTALCHARGES>25</TOTALCHARGES>
                <DESCRIPTION>J 19/7/01</DESCRIPTION>
                        </RECORD>
            <RECORD ID="2">
                <PID>3</PID>
                <ENTRYDATE>4/12/2002</ENTRYDATE>
                <VERSIONID>5/12/2018</VERSIONID>
                <REGDATE>30/6/1984</REGDATE>
                <EXPIREDDATE>23/4/2018</EXPIREDDATE>
                <TOTALCHARGES>544</TOTALCHARGES>
                <DESCRIPTION>G 24-1-01</DESCRIPTION>
                        </RECORD>
        </DATA>
    </TABLE>

    File B:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TABLE NAME="FILE_B">
    <DATA RECORDS="2">
        <RECORD ID="1">
            <PID>2</PID>
            <SN>2</SN>
            <OI>hjg</OI>
            <TEMPSTARTDATE>19/3/2003</TEMPSTARTDATE>
            <TEMPENDDATE>1/4/2015</TEMPENDDATE>
            <PCOD>0</PCOD>
            <NOTICEBY>1</NOTICEBY>
            <MAIN>8453304</MAIN>
        </RECORD>
        <RECORD ID="38">
            <PID>36</PID>
            <SN>2</SN>
            <OI>df</OI>
            <TEMPSTARTDATE>8/4/2003</TEMPSTARTDATE>
            <TEMPENDDATE>8/4/2004</TEMPENDDATE>
            <PCOD>0</PCOD>
            <CITY>PK</CITY>
            <NOTICEBY>0</NOTICEBY>
            <MAIN>697601</MAIN>
        </RECORD>
    </DATA>
</TABLE>
```

For each record (PID) of file A, we check if there is a record with the same PID (number) in file B. If there is a match, 
then i try to take specific elements info from the matching record (say the NOTICEBY and MAIN elements if they exist) from the matching record in file B, and put it in the DESCRIPTION element of the source record we investigate in file A. If a DESCRIPTION element doesnot exist in the record, we create one.

Also we need to have sorted the PID before the merging, since in one of my efforts i get an error:
Error executing XSLT at line 45 : Merge input for source saxon-merge-source-37386217 is not ordered according to merge key, detected at key value: ["36"]

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6r5Gh4c/4 
code so far:
https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6r5Gh4c/3

desired output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TABLE NAME="File_A">
    <DATA RECORDS="2">
        <RECORD ID="1">
            <PID>2</PID>
            <ENTRYDATE>4/12/2002</ENTRYDATE>
            <VERSIONID>28/12/2016</VERSIONID>
            <REGDATE>8/9/1986</REGDATE>
            <EXPIREDDATE>12/2/2010</EXPIREDDATE>
            <TOTALCHARGES>25</TOTALCHARGES>
            <DESCRIPTION>J 19/7/01  - info taken from file B - NOTICEBY: 1 - MAIN: 8453304</DESCRIPTION>
                    </RECORD>
        <RECORD ID="2">
            <PID>3</PID>
            <ENTRYDATE>4/12/2002</ENTRYDATE>
            <VERSIONID>5/12/2018</VERSIONID>
            <REGDATE>30/6/1984</REGDATE>
            <EXPIREDDATE>23/4/2018</EXPIREDDATE>
            <TOTALCHARGES>544</TOTALCHARGES>
            <DESCRIPTION>G 24-1-01</DESCRIPTION>
                    </RECORD>
    </DATA>
</TABLE>
```

Comment: So which is the first, which is the second input? A, B? Which of the two contains the `food` elements to be preserved and enhanced in the output, which of the two contains the ones to be ignored if they are not in the other input? In general you can name merge-sources with e.g. `<xsl:merge-source name="A" ...>` and then check e.g `<xsl:if test="current-merge-group('A')">...</xsl:if>` inside the merge action to only act/produce output there if you have data from that merge source.

Comment: @Martin i will rewrite the question, to make this clear, with my real data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the items to be merged are not sorted by the merge keys you want to use you need to make sure you use `sort-before-merge="yes"` on the relevant merge sources.

As for the task, if the items from the document "A" serve as the starting point then I would use that document as the primary input document and have the document "B" as a parameter `xsl:param name="doc-B"` (inlined in the sample but can of course be loaded from a file or URI in general with `<xsl:param name="doc-B" select="doc('fileB.xml')"/>`.

You seem to have more levels of elements so the merging should not be done in the template matching the root element but rather in the template matching the `DATA` elements.

One way to ensure you only get data from one source together with additional data from the other source is to name merge sources and use the name with `current-merge-group`, either in an `xsl:if` or as I tried below within the `select` attribute of the `xsl:copy`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    expand-text="yes"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:param name="doc-B">
<TABLE NAME="FILE_B">
    <DATA RECORDS="2">
        <RECORD ID="1">
            <PID>2</PID>
            <SN>2</SN>
            <OI>hjg</OI>
            <TEMPSTARTDATE>19/3/2003</TEMPSTARTDATE>
            <TEMPENDDATE>1/4/2015</TEMPENDDATE>
            <PCOD>0</PCOD>
            <NOTICEBY>1</NOTICEBY>
            <MAIN>8453304</MAIN>
        </RECORD>
        <RECORD ID="38">
            <PID>36</PID>
            <SN>2</SN>
            <OI>df</OI>
            <TEMPSTARTDATE>8/4/2003</TEMPSTARTDATE>
            <TEMPENDDATE>8/4/2004</TEMPENDDATE>
            <PCOD>0</PCOD>
            <CITY>PK</CITY>
            <NOTICEBY>0</NOTICEBY>
            <MAIN>697601</MAIN>
        </RECORD>
    </DATA>
</TABLE>
  </xsl:param>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="DATA[@RECORDS]">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
        <xsl:merge>
            <xsl:merge-source name="A" for-each-item="." select="RECORD" sort-before-merge="yes">
                <xsl:merge-key select="PID"/>
            </xsl:merge-source>
            <xsl:merge-source name="B" for-each-item="$doc-B" select="//RECORD" sort-before-merge="yes">
                <xsl:merge-key select="PID"/>
            </xsl:merge-source>
            <xsl:merge-action>
                <xsl:copy select="current-merge-group('A')">
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*, *">
                        <xsl:with-param name="merge-data" 
                          select="let $data := string-join(current-merge-group()[2]/(NOTICEBY, MAIN)!(name() || ': ' || .), ' - ')
                                  return if (description)
                                         then ' - info taken from file ' || document-uri(root(current-merge-group()[2])) || $data
                                         else $data"/>
                    </xsl:apply-templates>
                </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:merge-action>
        </xsl:merge>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="RECORD/DESCRIPTION">
      <xsl:param name="merge-data"/>
      <xsl:copy>{.}{$merge-data}</xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="RECORD[not(DESCRIPTION)]/*[last()]">
      <xsl:param name="merge-data"/>
      <xsl:next-match/>
      <DESCRIPTION>{$merge-data}</DESCRIPTION>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6r5Gh4c/5

Comment: i get `Type error evaluating (fn:current-merge-group(...)) in xsl:copy/@select on line 25 column 61 of test.xsl:
  XTTE3180: A sequence of more than one item is not allowed as the @select attribute of
  xsl:copy (<RECORD>, <RECORD>, ...)
     invoked by unknown caller (null)
  In template rule with match="DATA[@RECORDS]" on line 14 of testxsl
     invoked by built-in template rule (shallow-copy)
     invoked by built-in template rule (shallow-copy)
A sequence of more than one item is not allowed as the @select attribute of xsl:copy (<RECORD>, <RECORD>, ...)`

Comment: Do you get that error with the code as posted and with the samples as shown in https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6r5Gh4c/5? If so, which XSLT processor exactly do you use? Is there any chance the source file A has several `RECORD`s with the same `PID`?

Comment: exactly. my problem. Onlu issue i see is unneeded addition of the - info taken from file  when there is no match: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6r5Gh4c/6 to be clear i am totally good with the solution, been struggling for more than a week

Comment: I think the condition should now be `if (current-merge-group('B')/DESCRIPTION)`, as in https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6r5Gh4c/7. As we have moved to named merge sources, it is probably cleaner to use the names in all references and not to rely on the position, so the other uses of `current-merge-group()` can be changed as I have tried in https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6r5Gh4c/8.

Comment: thank you for an excellent solution and thorough documentation